# E: Unable to locate package ros-VERSION-velodyne

Tags: velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I followed the instructions and installed ROS.  When I try to do the step from [Getting Started with the Velodyne HDL-32E](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20the%20HDL-32E) "Install the Velodyne stack from the repositories by running `sudo apt-get install ros-VERSION-velodyne`" I get the following error:

```
user@user:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-VERSION-velodyne
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
**E: Unable to locate package ros-VERSION-velodyne**
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252416/e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-version-velodyne/) by [J0rd4n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29114/j0rd4n/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> sudo apt-get install ros-VERSION-velodyne
> ```

you are expected to replace `VERSION` with the ROS version that you are running.

So for Indigo, you'd use:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-velodyne
```

Note: the `velodyne` packages have not yet been released into Kinetic, so `ros-kinetic-velodyne` will not work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Masha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29117/masha/) on 2017-01-19**:
Do you know when the kinetic version might be released?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-19**:
No, I don't. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/issues/93) about it though.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-01-20**:
Soon, I hope. Meanwhile, build it from source; that does work.

**Comment by [Albertx](https://answers.ros.org/users/29836/albertx/) on 2017-03-29**:
How about jade?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-03-29**:
Jade should build from source, too. If it does not work, please open a github issue.

**Comment by [Albertx](https://answers.ros.org/users/29836/albertx/) on 2017-03-29**:
@joq, any instructions on how to build from source?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-03-29**:
Like this http://answers.ros.org/question/226594/how-do-i-build-ros-vlp16-velodyne-driver-for-indigo-using-catkin/

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-03-29**:
Substitute `jade` for `indigo`, of course.